# What does Node.JS support on a hosting plan mean?

Tags: hosting, node.js, shared-hosting

As I was browsing various hosting plans, I noticed that some offer `Node.JS` support.
If a host does not offer `Node.JS`; Can I log in, download, and install `Node.JS` support myself if the host supports SSH?

I am confused on what Node.JS support means in a hosting plan.
Can someone help me understand it?

Tl;dr:

- On a shared host: Can I install `Node.JS` support with an `SSH` connection?
- Can someone explain what `Node.JS` support means on a shared host?

Comment: Hard to say without specifics, but as you've tagged this "shared-hosting", there's a good chance you won't be allowed to install node on your own at all.

Comment: how can they control that though? It's not like they can detect whether something is nodejs and whether something is not. SSH is supported

Comment: Sure they can. `ps aux | grep node`. They'll probably also notice the resource usage - shared hosting typically has strict CPU and RAM limits - and you won't be able to bind to port 80/443 either.

Comment: SSH support does not mean you can reconfigure the webserver to execute things you might download. So while you might be able to download nodejs yourself, you would at the most be able to use it to manage your files, not to generate webpages.

Answer (score 1):

`Node.JS` installed on a shared host means that the hosting platform supports running `Node.JS` apps (apps that have a `package.json` file).

You can't simply install `Node.JS` on a shared host platform as the hosting service is being provided to you as a Platform as a Service architecture.
A `PaaS` architecture means that the hosting provider is responsible for the hosting fabric from the physical hardware to the operating system to the hosting frameworks (`Apache`, `Node.JS`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, and so on).
You are responsible for building your app and getting it on their fabric.
So the hosting provider will provide filesystem access to allow you to upload your app to their fabric.

Because you do not have access to the operating system, you will not be able to install new hosting apps into the fabric. That means that you will want to make sure that the host has all of frameworks installed and up to date so that your app that you want to host will be able to run.

`Node.JS` needs to be installed into the operating system to run, which means that you will not be able to deploy it into a `PaaS` host.

If the host is giving you a virtual machine (`IaaS`), you can do whatever you want to in it as you have full control over the operating system.
Excluding some `MAC address` stuff as that goes into the physical layer side of things.

I hope this helps

Thanks!

Comment: great explaination

Comment: @Jaden, did I answer your question?